# Is the prefix "di-" more Latin-like than "bi-"?

Tags: etymology, greek, prefix, reference-request

**Question.**

(1) Is there anything close to scientifically-meaningful to say about whether the prefix "di-" is *more Latin* than the prefix "bi-", when indicating *two-ness*?

(2) Are there published scholarly references *on precisely this question*, comparing the two prefixes?

(3) Are there notable Latin words which *simultaneously* contain "bi" and "di"?

**Remarks.**

- In a vague sense that I have no time or experience enough to substantiate, this seems to be the case, "di-" seeming significantly more Latin-ish than "bi-" which seems more Greek-ish.

EDIT: like kindly pointed out by the responders, here this attribution of bi to Greek and di to Latin was an accidental **mix-up**. It is the other way round: bi is Latin, di is Greek.

- Of course, the difference is not clear-cut, there is organic growth and randomness involved, and e.g. in Greek *both* "bi-" and "di-" appear in composites.
- Both "bi-" and "di-" appear in countless scientific terms.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### *di-* is Greek and *bi-* is Latin

The Proto-Indo-European root for "two" is reconstructed as **dw-*. The remnants of this *w* can be seen in English "two", Russian *dva*, Ancient Greek *δύο*, and many other languages, as well as Latin *duo*, "two".

Old Latin had many words starting with *dv-* (where *v* was pronounced as English "w"). But at some point before Classical times, *dv-* changed into *b-* at the beginning of words. Hence *dvellum* (whence English "duel") became *bellum* "war", and *dvonos* became *bonus* "good".

The word *duo* "two" itself had a vowel *u* rather than a consonant *v*, so it avoided the change. But the prefix *dvi-* was affected by the change, and became *bi-*. A similar thing happened in Ancient Greek, which lost the *w* sound entirely, giving *δι-*.

So strictly speaking, *di-* should be used only on Greek roots, and *bi-* on Latin. But in practice Greek and Latin are mixed together all over the place and the prefix is generally chosen based on what sounds better.

(Compare also the prefixes *semi-* from Latin and *hemi-* from Greek, which are sometimes even combined, as in the musical term "hemidemisemiquaver". They're also cognates; *s-* before vowels at the beginning of words changed into *h-* in Greek.)

(ETA: Joonas suggested an even clearer pair of cognates, Latin *super-* and Greek *hyper-*. Many thanks.)

Comment: Perhaps a better known pair of Latin and Greek prefixes is super- and hyper-. Combining the two is a form of exaggeration.

Comment: The reason *u* was kept in *duo* isn't frequency, but that this *u* was a vowel [u] rather than the consonant [w] as in *duellum*. Similarly for Greek δύο  vs. δι-.

Comment: @TKR I thought it was analyzed as a vowel in *duellum* also (making the word trisyllabic)?

Comment: It's such a shame that the modern greek word for biscuit/cookie is "μπισκότο" (biscotto), not διμαγειρεμένος or something.

Comment: duo is from the bisyllabic *duwo-. bis is from the monosyllabic *dwi-. These two forms both go back to proto-Indo-European. It is not about the relative frequency of the two words in Latin.

Comment: It's hemidemisemiquaver, not hemisemidemiquaver.

Comment: *Duellum* is assumed to be bisyllabic; a change [dw] > [b] is much more plausible than [du] > [b].

Answer (score 12):

Your are confused; *bi-* is Latin and *di-* is Greek.  There is no real difference in meaning between them, but in usage *bi-* is used with Latin constructions like *bisexual* and *di-* with Greek constructions like *diglossia*.  *bi-* is *not* a Greek prefix.

(As an aside, I should mention that both Latin bi- and Greek δι‐ have a common origin in a reconstructed ancestor *dwi- .)

Comment: To add to this, Old Latin *du-* regularly changes to Classical Latin *b-;* e.g. *duellum* -> *bellum* 'war'. This is why we have both *duo* 'two' (disyllabic) and *bis* 'twice', the latter from *duis* (monosyllabic).

Comment: @Anonym. To be more precise: IE *dw becomes Latin b in initial position only. IE *du remains du in Latin in all positions.